# Slow List Comprehension with Regex

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, performance, python-3.8

Suppose I have a list of files, such as the following:

```
['regular0000.png', 'regular0001.png', 'regular0002.png', 
 'depth.0000.png', 'emission0000.png', 'emission0001.png',   
 'emission0002.png', 'diffusefilter0000.png']
```

My goal is to keep all "png sequences" in this list; in other words, all pngs with prefixes that appear more than once. For example, I would like to filter the list to obtain:

```
['regular0000.png', 'regular0001.png', 'regular0002.png', 
 'emission0000.png', 'emission0001.png', 'emission0002.png']
```

I wrote the following list comprehension to do this, but for large PNG sequences (1000+ files), it starts to get really slow.

```
prefix_regex = r'(.*)[0-9]{4,}\.png'
pngs = glob.glob(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), folder, "*.png"))
pngs = [png for png in pngs if sum((re.search(prefix_regex, 
         png2).group(1) == re.search(prefix_regex, png).group(1)) 
             for png2 in pngs) > 1]
```

Anyone know how I can speed this list comprehension up? I'm using Python 3.8 if that can help.

Comment: Use `re.compile()` to convert the regexp into a more efficient form.

Comment: Do you actually have file names that do *not* match the ``<name><number>.png`` scheme? If you don't actually have to parse anything, just sorting the files (to force each ``<name>`` sequence to be one run), getting the prefix (slicing up to the last non-numeric character) and comparing that against the next element would be a single-pass approach with little computation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a regex with `.groupby`:

```
from itertools import groupby 
import re


li=['regular0000.png', 'regular0001.png', 'regular0002.png', 
 'depth.0000.png', 'emission0000.png', 'emission0001.png',   
 'emission0002.png', 'diffusefilter0000.png']

for k,v in groupby(sorted(li), key=lambda s: re.search(r'(^[^\d]+)', s).group(1)):
    print(k,list(v))
```

Prints:

```
depth. ['depth.0000.png']
diffusefilter ['diffusefilter0000.png']
emission ['emission0000.png', 'emission0001.png', 'emission0002.png']
regular ['regular0000.png', 'regular0001.png', 'regular0002.png']
```

Then if you want only groups:

```
for k,v in groupby(sorted(li), key=lambda s: re.search(r'(^[^\d]+)', s).group(1)):
    tgt=list(v)
    if len(tgt)>1: print(tgt)
```

If I run this with your example `*10000` it completes the entire list in 152 ms...

Comment: Thanks, this worked great, but I had to use two lines to do it:
`newpngs = [tgt for k,v in groupby(sorted(pngs), key=lambda s: re.search(prefix_regex, s).group(1)) if len(tgt:=list(v)) > 1]` followed by 
`newpngs = [item for sublist in newpngs for item in sublist]`. I'm not sure if it can be done in one line.

Comment: If you **have** to have one line: `list(chain(*[tgt for k,v in groupby(sorted(li), key=lambda s: re.search(r'(^[^\d]+)', s).group(1)) if len(tgt:=list(v)) > 1]))`

Answer (score 2):

In this specific case, I'd recommend making a `collections.defaultdict(list)` and doing a single pass over your files, `append`ing each file to the `list` keyed by the prefix you extract. That replaces all-to-all comparisons, `O(n**2)`, with a cheap grouping operation, `O(n)`; for 1000 files, that means reducing work proportional to ~1,000,000 to ~1000.

Side-note: A couple general optimizations to know about:

1. When you only care about getting a single hit, don't do `sum(...) > 1`; replace it with `any(...)` so it short-circuits as soon as you get a hit. It won't fix big-O performance (your big problem here), but it's useful in other cases.
2. Pre-compile your regex with `re.compile` and use the `search` of the compiled regex object (`re` does cache the compiled forms of regex, but it still needs to do cache lookup over and over; compiling and saving the compiled regex yourself avoids that work)

Answer (score 0):

Here is an answer using the `defaultdict` approach described by @ShadowRanger:

```
from collections import defaultdict
import os
import string

imgs = ['regular0000.png', 'regular0001.png', 'regular0002.png', 'depth.0000.png', 'emission0000.png', 'emission0001.png', 'emission0002.png', 'diffusefilter0000.png']

d = defaultdict(list)
for i in imgs:
    name, ext = os.path.splitext(i)
    no_num = name.rstrip(string.digits)
    d[no_num].append(i)

result = [i for  _, v in d.items() if len(v) > 1 for i in v]
```

This at least is still instantaneous when multiplying the original `imgs` list by `1000`.